# Make an app available to Priority App in Focus Assist on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, notifications, nsis, windows-shell

I have a python app that I'm installing with NSIS. What I cant figure out is how you get an App into the "priority list" that is in the Focus Assist area of windows. The dialog suggests you can add any app - but you can't. Its a really small amount of apps that are available. How can you make an app available to this Focus Assist priority list?

It might have something to do with [AUMID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid). You need to set this when you install your app. When using NSIS these two options don't seem to fix this issue

- https://github.com/safing/nsis-shortcut-properties
- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/WinShell_plug-in

[image: Priority Apps list in Focus Assist on Windows 10]

Comment: How is the NSIS tag relevant? Try adding tags about Windows shell instead...

Comment: Fair comment.. I'll do that - for anyone else coming to this from NSIS in the future - there are two solutions that dont seem to work. https://github.com/safing/nsis-shortcut-properties and https://nsis.sourceforge.io/WinShell_plug-in - well dont seem to help in the way of making it available as a priority app.

Comment: Do you have normal notifications working? I can help you with the NSIS part but first you would have to find the documentation that lists the requirements or API to call...

Comment: Yeah I do @Anders its pretty simple to get that working. https://github.com/ms7m/notify-py#usage - pyinstaller on that python file. works. But I'm getting a NSIS installer error when trying this nsis-shortcut-props technique - see https://github.com/AceCentre/RelayKeys/blob/e7c6ece174f64105e19e70658a3d50c6a1e2ea95/build-installer.nsi#L150 (I feel some SO admin is going to step in any minute now..)

Comment: Compiler error?

Comment: Compiles - but on running it breaks - get warning here  https://github.com/AceCentre/RelayKeys/blob/e7c6ece174f64105e19e70658a3d50c6a1e2ea95/build-installer.nsi#L153 - and  "Add Toast-Properties to Shortcut
Error-Point: Load Shortcut
Error-Code: -2147024894"

Comment: -2147024894 is can't find the file

Comment: OMG - how long have I been googling that err num..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246795/discussion-between-willwade-and-anders).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if setting the ToastActivatorCLSID is going to help but here is some NSIS code to do that. I noticed that OneDrive also sets the ID so this function sets both:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Win\COM.nsh
!include Win\Propkey.nsh

Function SetLnkToastActivatorCLSIDAndAUMI
System::Store S
Pop $3
Pop $4
Pop $6
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_ShellLink} ${IID_IShellLink} r1 ""
${If} $1 P<> 0
    ${IUnknown::QueryInterface} $1 '("${IID_IPersistFile}",.r2)'
    ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
    ${If} $2 P<> 0
        ${IPersistFile::Load} $2 '(r3,${STGM_READWRITE})i.r0'
        ${If} $0 >= 0
            ${IUnknown::QueryInterface} $2 '("${IID_IPropertyStore}",.r1)'
            ${If} $1 P<> 0
                System::Call '*${SYSSTRUCT_PROPERTYKEY}(${PKEY_AppUserModel_ToastActivatorCLSID})p.r3'
                System::Call '*(&g16"$4")p.r4'
                System::Call '*${SYSSTRUCT_PROPVARIANT}(${VT_CLSID},,p$4)p.r5'
                ${IPropertyStore::SetValue} $1 '($3,$5)i.r0'
                System::Free $4
                ${If} $6 != ""
                    System::Call '*$3${SYSSTRUCT_PROPERTYKEY}(${PKEY_AppUserModel_ID})'
                    System::Call '*(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}s)p.r4' $6
                    ${V_SetPointer} $5 ${VT_LPWSTR} $4
                    ${IPropertyStore::SetValue} $1 '($3,$5)'
                    System::Free $4
                ${EndIf}
                ${IPropertyStore::Commit} $1 ""
                System::Free $3
                System::Free $5
                ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
                ${If} $0 >= 0
                    ${IPersistFile::Save} $2 '(p0,1)'
                ${EndIf}
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
        ${IUnknown::Release} $2 ""
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
!macro SetLnkToastActivatorCLSIDAndAUMI lnkpath clsid aumi
Push "${aumi}"
Push ${clsid}
Push "${lnkpath}"
Call SetLnkToastActivatorCLSIDAndAUMI
!macroend

Section 
!define MYTOASTCLASSGUID {696a4cab-ef17-48d1-8bb5-6ebc36b94d0a} ; Replace this with your own CLSID
CreateShortcut /NoWorkingDir "$SMPrograms\NSIS_toast_test.lnk" "$sysdir\winver.exe"
!insertmacro SetLnkToastActivatorCLSIDAndAUMI "$SMPrograms\NSIS_toast_test.lnk" ${MYTOASTCLASSGUID} "My.AppModel.Id.Goes.Here"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Maybe its me - but I'm not finding that working. I'm using these techniques to hunt for the AUMID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app

Comment: Why would you need to hunt, you can invent one for your own app...